# IPEndPoint IP address

Tags: c#

I am looking at network chat on UDP port (network chat demo using naudio) between two machines. The application uses IPEndPoint. How can I change the following line to use remote machine's IP address?

```
udpSender = new UdpClient();
udpListener = new UdpClient();
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(textBoxPort.Text));

udpListener.Client.Bind(endPoint);
udpSender.Connect(endPoint);
```

The udpListener binds to 0.0.0.0 but udpSender gives an error "The requested address is not valid in its context 0.0.0.0:7080"

Comment: Please give us a more complete example of your code.

Comment: Listeners do not connect. They listen on inbound traffic.

Comment: @jgauffin I am binding my listener but sender would connect?

Comment: You bind your sender to the ip-address 0.0.0.0. That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UdpSender should connect to a specific ip address. `0.0.0.0` means that the server should accept connections on any of the local addresses.

Connections however needs to be done on a specific IP:

```
//server. accepts connections
IPEndPoint serverPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(textBoxPort.Text));
udpListener = new UdpClient();
udpListener.Client.Bind(serverPoint );

//client, need a specific IP. Loopback = 127.0.0.1
IPEndPoint clientPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, int.Parse(textBoxPort.Text));
udpSender = new UdpClient();
udpSender.Connect(clientPoint );
```